# What happens when I resize this vector (of vectors)

Tags: c++, vector

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecOfVecs;
vecOfVecs.resize(10);
```

What will be positions 0-9 of vecOfVecs? Instances of std::vector?

If so, is this legitimate:

```
std::vector<int> *pToVec = &(vecOfVecs[0]);
pToVec->push_back(10);
```

Comment: Totally legitimate. I think you've got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "canonical" definition of `std::vector::resize` in C++03 actually has *two* parameters, not one, with the second argument being the element value that is used as a "fill value" for the freshly created elements. The second parameter has a default argument equal to a value-initialized object of element type. This means that your call

```
vecOfVecs.resize(10);
```

is actually translated into a

```
vecOfVecs.resize(10, std::vector<int>());
```

call. I.e. it is actually you who implicitly supplied a default-constructed instance of `std::vector<int>` to be used as an initializer for all new elements.

Your `pToVec->push_back(10)` call is perfectly legitimate.

C++11 made some insignificant (in this context) changes to the definition of `resize`, but the general effect remains the same: the new elements are value-initialized for you. They are ready to be used immediately after the call to `resize`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, positions 0-9 will be empty instances of `std::vector<int>`, exactly as if you had said

```
for (size_t i = vecOfVecs.size(); i < 10; ++i) {
    vecOfVecs.push_back(std::vector<int>());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a default second parameter of `resize` that tells what value you'd like to insert into the additional space. If that value is not specified, the default-constructed value is used instead.

```
void resize (size_type n, value_type val = value_type());
```

> If `n` is greater than the current container size, the content is expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach a size of `n`. If `val` is specified, the new elements are initialized as copies of `val`, otherwise, they are value-initialized.

Your example is entirely legitimate: your vector of vectors will contain ten empty vectors.

Comment: C++11 changes it so that there are two overloads: `resize(size_type)` and `resize(size_type, const T &)` (w/o a defaulted argument). In C++11 `resize(n)` will default construct the created elements, whereas in C++03 it default constructs the default argument and then copy-constructs the created elements.